# SFTP connection throws odd FileTransferException that exposes SFTP password

Tags: java, sftp

It is really bizarre, why would zehon return my location of my eclipse, and my SFTP password as *part of a FileSystemException*?

I have checked that the remote host is indeed a SFTP server, and the client is connecting using SFTP.

Zehon API [here](http://www.zehon.com/javadocs/com/zehon/sftp/SFTPClient.html)

**Stacktrace**

```
 Reading file from C:\srcFolde\FileToBeUploaded.zip
    com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException:
    org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: 
    Unknown message with code:
        "C:<location of eclipse>/<sftp password>?" does not exist
        at int result = sftp.sendFile(filePath, ftpDestFolder);
```

**Code**

```
SFTPClient sftp = new SFTPClient(ftpServer, 22, ftpUserName, ftpPassword, true);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);                
            String filePath=fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-4) + ".zip";
            String ftpDestFolder="\\sftpDestFolder";
            int result = sftp.sendFile(filePath, ftpDestFolder);
            Logger.debug("sftp result = " + result);
        } catch (FileTransferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the wrong constructor. From the Javadocs

http://www.zehon.com/javadocs/com/zehon/sftp/SFTPClient.html

You've passed `ftpPassword` where it's expecting `privateKeyPath`.